# Python - Crontab script not showing Pillow Images

Tags: python, linux, cron, boot, python-imaging-library

My crontab is

```
@reboot /home/cin/new.sh
```

In new.sh I have

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 new.py
```

In new.py I open images with the Pillow module and play music, but when I boot it only plays the music. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The music plays perfectly.

Edit: The shell script runs it fine in terminal.

ANSWERED!

Comment: Since the problem is obviously the python code, how about posting the relevant code? Just an idea.

Comment: Also it may be a problem in $PATH. First of all ensure that `new.py` starts from cron - for example add writing to file to first line of script.

Comment: @PavelPatrin ?? How would I make new.py start  from cron? You mean directly?

Comment: I mean from cron. You could for example add record `* * * * * /home/cin/new.sh`

Comment: @PavelPatrin What would the stars do? Wildcards*

Comment: Oh, i missed tnat music is playing. So, script starts ok.

Comment: Show code of a script.

Comment: Here it is from memory: Import image import subprocess my image = image.open(image name) my image.show() to show the images

Comment: I had to install the image module with pip.

Comment: `Show()` calls the `xv` utility to display the image. `Xv` uses xserver to display image. So you need all xserver env variables to run `xv`.

Comment: Alright, how do I do that?

Comment: Try to add to bash script before calling python: `export DISPLAY=":0.0"`.

Comment: Yes sir! I'll do this.

Comment: Kinda like you  do in ssh to allow gui applications to be opened on whoever you're connecting to's computer

Comment: Restarting computer...

Comment: This seems to be working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the bash script, write `export DISPLAY=":0.0`.